# Range query on LocalDateTime in Hibernate Search 6

Tags: hibernate-search

I'm planning to switch from Hibernate Search 5.11 to 6, but can't find the way to query DSL for range query on LocalDateTime. I prefer to use native Lucene QueryParser.  In previous version I used NumericRangeQuery, because using @FieldBridge (convert to long value).

Here are my previous version codes.

```
    @Entity 
    ...
       @NumericField //convert to long value
        @FieldBridge(impl = LongLocalDateTimeFieldBridge.class) 
        @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.NO)
        private LocalDateTime createDate;
...
```

These are QueryParser

```
     public class NumericLocalDateRangeQueryParser extends QueryParser {
    
        private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
        private String f;
        private static final Long DEFAULT_DATE = -1L;
        private String dateFormat;
        public NumericLocalDateRangeQueryParser(final String f, final Analyzer a) {
            super(f, a);
            this.f = f;
        }
    
        public NumericLocalDateRangeQueryParser(final String dateFormat,final String f, Analyzer a) {
            super(f, a);
            this.f = f;
            this.dateFormat = dateFormat;
            logger.debug("date formate: {}", ()->dateFormat);
        }
    
          
        //check a field if found, have to set to -1
        @Override
        protected Query newFieldQuery(Analyzer analyzer, String field, String queryText, boolean quoted) throws ParseException {
            if (f.equals(field)) {
                 try {
                     return NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange(
                            field,
                            stringToTime(queryText).toEpochDay(), stringToTime(queryText).toEpochDay(),
                            true,
                            true
                    );
                } catch (final DateTimeParseException ex) {
                    
                    return super.newFieldQuery(analyzer, field, queryText, quoted);
                     
                }
            }
          
            return super.newFieldQuery(analyzer, field, queryText, quoted);  
        }
    
        /**
         *
         * @param field = filed when indexing
         * @param part1 = date 1 e.g. date 1 to date 2 in string
         * @param part2 = date 2
         * @param startInclusive
         * @param endInclusive
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        protected Query newRangeQuery(final String field, final String part1, final String part2,
                final boolean startInclusive, final boolean endInclusive) {
    
            if (f.equals(field)) {
    
                try {
                    return NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange(
                            field,
                            stringToTime(part1).toEpochDay(), stringToTime(part2).toEpochDay(),
                            true,
                            true
                    );
    
                } catch (final DateTimeParseException ex) {
                    return NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange(field, DEFAULT_DATE, DEFAULT_DATE, true, true);
                }
            } else {
                return super.newRangeQuery(field, part1, part2, startInclusive, endInclusive);
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        protected org.apache.lucene.search.Query newTermQuery(final Term term) { 
 if (term.field().equals(f)) {
                try {
                    return NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange(term.field(),
                            stringToTime(term.text()).toEpochDay(), stringToTime(term.text()).toEpochDay(), true, true);
    
                } catch (final DateTimeParseException ex) {
                    logger.debug("it's not numeric: {}", () -> ex.getMessage());
                    return NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange(field, DEFAULT_DATE,DEFAULT_DATE, true, true);
                }
            } else {
                logger.debug("normal query term");
                return super.newTermQuery(term);
            }
        }
    
        private LocalDate stringToTime(final String date) throws DateTimeParseException {
           final  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat);
            return LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
    
        }
       
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, on the mapping side, you'll just need this:

```java
       @GenericField
       private LocalDateTime createDate;
```

Second, the query. If you really want to write native queries and skip the whole [Search DSL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl), I suppose you have your reasons. Would you mind sharing them in a comment? Maybe it'll give me some ideas for improvements in Hibernate Search.

Regardless, the underlying queries changed a lot between Lucene 5 and 8. You can find how we query long-based fields (such as `LocalDateTime`) [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/a1fdbecb424e41e5b090f20b2eb4cab3aa329e12/backend/lucene/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/backend/lucene/types/lowlevel/impl/LuceneLongDomain.java#L70), and how we convert a `LocalDateTime` to a long [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/a1fdbecb424e41e5b090f20b2eb4cab3aa329e12/backend/lucene/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/backend/lucene/types/codec/impl/LuceneLocalDateTimeFieldCodec.java#L56).

So, something like this should work:

```java
long part1AsLong = stringToTime(part1).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli();
long part2AsLong = stringToTime(part2).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli();
Query query = LongPoint.newRangeQuery(field, part1AsLong, part2AsLong);
```

---

Alternatively, if you can rely on the Search DSL, you can do this:

```java
SearchSession searchSession = Search.session(entityManager);
SearchScope<MyEntity> scope = searchSession.scope(MyEntity.class);
// Pass the scope to your query parser somehow
MyQueryParser parser = new MyQueryParser(..., scope);

// Then in your parser, do this to create a range query on a `LocalDateTime` field:
LocalDateTime part1AsDateTime = stringToTime(part1);
LocalDateTime part2AsDateTime = stringToTime(part2);
Query query = LuceneMigrationUtils.toLuceneQuery(scope.predicate().range()
        .field(field)
        .between(part1AsDateTime, part2AsDateTime)
        .toPredicate());
```

Note however that `LuceneMigrationUtils` is SPI, and as such it could change or be removed in a later version. If you think it's useful, we could expose it as API in a future version, so that it's guaranteed to stay there.

---

I suspect we could address your problem better by adding something to Hibernate Search, though. Why exactly do you need to rely on a query parser?

Comment: Thank you. I've tried with your idea. Now I can search LccalDateTime. The reason I use query parser is I familiar with it. But if your way is better, I'll consider/try to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my codes (modified from previous version):

```
    public class LongPointLocalDateTimeRangeQueryParser extends QueryParser {
    
        private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
        private String f;
        private static final Long DEFAULT_DATE = -1L;
        private String dateFormat;
    
        public LongPointLocalDateTimeRangeQueryParser(final String f, final Analyzer a) {
            super(f, a);
            this.f = f;
        }
    
        public LongPointLocalDateTimeRangeQueryParser(final String dateFormat, final String f, Analyzer a) {
            super(f, a);
            this.f = f;
            this.dateFormat = dateFormat; 
        }
     
        @Override
        protected Query newFieldQuery(Analyzer analyzer, String field, String queryText, boolean quoted) throws ParseException {
            if (f.equals(field)) {
                logger.debug("newFieldQuery, with field: {}, queryText: {}, quoted: {}", () -> f, () -> queryText, () -> quoted);
                try {      
                    return LongPoint.newRangeQuery(
                            field,
                            stringToTime(queryText).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli(), stringToTime(queryText).plusDays(1).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()
                    );
    
                } catch (final DateTimeParseException ex) {
                    logger.debug("it's not date format, error: {}", () -> ex.getMessage());
                    return super.newFieldQuery(analyzer, field, queryText, quoted);
                    //return null;
                }
            }
            logger.debug("newFieldQuery, normal, queryText: {}, quoted: {}", () -> queryText, () -> quoted);
            return super.newFieldQuery(analyzer, field, queryText, quoted); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    
        /**
         *
         * @param field = filed when indexing
         * @param part1 = date 1 in string
         * @param part2 = date 2
         * @param startInclusive
         * @param endInclusive
         * @return
         */
        @Override
        protected Query newRangeQuery(final String field, final String part1, final String part2,
                final boolean startInclusive, final boolean endInclusive) {
            if (f.equals(field)) {
                try {
            logger.debug("date 1: {}, str: {}", () -> stringToTime(part1).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli(), () -> part1);
            logger.debug("date 2: {}, str: {}", () -> stringToTime(part2).plusDays(1).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli(), () -> part2);
                    return LongPoint.newRangeQuery(
                            field,
                            stringToTime(part1).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli(), stringToTime(part2).plusDays(1).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()
                    );
                } catch (final DateTimeParseException ex) {
                    logger.debug("it's not date format, error: {}", () -> ex.getMessage());
                    return LongPoint.newRangeQuery(field, DEFAULT_DATE, DEFAULT_DATE);
                }
            } else {
                logger.debug("normal query range");
                return super.newRangeQuery(field, part1, part2, startInclusive, endInclusive);
            }
        }
    
        private LocalDateTime stringToTime(final String date) throws DateTimeParseException {
   //... same as previous posted
        }
}
```

And this is query parser

```
//... 
    final SearchQuery<POSProcessInventory> result = searchSession.search(POSProcessInventory.class).extension(LuceneExtension.get())
                        .where(f -> f.bool(b -> {
                     b.must(f.bool(b1 -> {
    //...
      try {
                            if (searchWord.contains("createDate:")) {
                                logger.info("doing queryParser for LocalDateTime: {}", () -> searchWord);
                                b1.should(f.fromLuceneQuery(queryLocalDateTime("createDate", searchWord)));
                            }
                        } catch (ParseException ex) {
                            logger.error("#3 this is not localDateTime");
                        }
```

And another method

```
 private org.apache.lucene.search.Query queryLocalDateTime(final String field, final String dateTime)
            throws org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException {
        final LongPointLocalDateTimeRangeQueryParser createDateQ = new LongPointLocalDateTimeRangeQueryParser(accessCompanyInfo.getDateTimeFormat().substring(0, 10), field, new KeywordAnalyzer());
        createDateQ.setAllowLeadingWildcard(false);  
        final org.apache.lucene.search.Query queryLocalDate = createDateQ.parse(dateTime);
        logger.debug(field + "query field: {} query Str: {}", () -> field, () -> queryLocalDate);
        return queryLocalDate;
    }
```